# How to show ActivityIndictor when data is fetched in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app with PHP backEnd (SQL server DB)

Well ,As you see in pictures ,I have a form where user can enter month and year and search DB's information ;

My code do:

1/ if a variable is setting true => I will get just my form

2/ if I click on button => variable became false and show the form and data ;

My problem is when I click on button ,it takes some time to show results so in this case I wan add an ActivityIndicator as a sign that something is working behind ;

[image: when button is clicked]

[image]

This is my code :

```
export default class FirstPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    isLoading: true,
    dataSource: [],
    month:'',
    year:'',
  }
  }

  afficher = () =>{
    this.setState({
       Loading: false})
   const month = this.state.month;
   const year= this.state.year;
   return fetch('http://192.168.1.2:80/netOne/fetch.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({mois:month,annee:year})})
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
if(responseJson=="null"){

 }
else {this.setState({
   isLoading: false,
   dataSource: responseJson,});}}
       )
     .catch((error) =>{console.error(error);});

     this.setState({
     month:'',
     year:'',})
 }



  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{marginTop:30,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',height:150}}>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Month :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,paddingLeft:5,marginRight:20,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {month=>this.setState({month})}/>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Year :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,paddingLeft:5,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {year=>this.setState({year})}/>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius:12,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ff9900',height:50,marginTop:10}} onPress={this.afficher}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:15,color:'white',textAlign:'center',fontSize:14}}>Afficher</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
     </View>
)}

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2'}}>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{marginTop:30,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',height:150}}>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Month :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,paddingLeft:5,marginRight:20,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {month=>this.setState({month})}/>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Year :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,paddingLeft:5,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {year=>this.setState({year})}/>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius:12,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ff9900',height:50,marginTop:10}} onPress={this.afficher}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:15,color:'white',textAlign:'center',fontSize:14}}>Afficher</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
        <View style={{ paddingLeft:10 ,paddingTop:10 ,paddingBottom:10}}>
      <View  style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
      <Text  style={styles.head}> Client </Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head1}>Mois</Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head2}>Annee</Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head3}>ChiffreAffaire</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) =><Item title={item.M500_NOM} title1={item.Mois} title2={item.Annee} title3={item.ChiffreAffaire}/>}
      ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

      />
      </View>

</ScrollView>
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code.

```
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2'}}>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{marginTop:30,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',height:150}}>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Month :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,paddingLeft:5,marginRight:20,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {month=>this.setState({month})}/>
      <Text style={{marginTop:20,marginLeft:20,color:'grey'}}> Year :</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter value" style={{marginLeft:20,marginRight:20,paddingLeft:5,borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',borderBottomWidth: 1,}} onChangeText= {year=>this.setState({year})}/>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius:12,width:Dimensions.get("window").width*0.8,backgroundColor:'#ff9900',height:50,marginTop:10}} onPress={this.afficher}>
        <Text style={{marginTop:15,color:'white',textAlign:'center',fontSize:14}}>Afficher</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
{(this.state.dataSource.length != 0) </View>
        <View style={{ paddingLeft:10 ,paddingTop:10 ,paddingBottom:10}}>
      <View  style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
      <Text  style={styles.head}> Client </Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head1}>Mois</Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head2}>Annee</Text>
      <Text  style={styles.head3}>ChiffreAffaire</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) =><Item title={item.M500_NOM} title1={item.Mois} title2={item.Annee} title3={item.ChiffreAffaire}/>}
      ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

      />
      </View>}
{this.state.loading && 
    <ActivityIndicator/>
}

</ScrollView>
    );
```

Comment: Hello Anurodh Singh ;thank for your help but it didn't work for me maybe there is an error in syntax or code  !!! If you discovred the problem ,please tell me!!!